# Replacing strings in file - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to improve a translation script I've seen online so that it can take in a document and replace words surrounded by ' ' by their translations.

The translation work nicely, but my problem comes from when I try to make the replacement.
It doesn't do it at all and duplicate the last character on my file.

This is my input file :

```
'Who'
'Where'
'How'
'Test' : 'Sun' : 'Water'
```

And this is my output :

```
'Who'
'Where'
'How'
'Test' : 'Sun' : 'Water'''''''
```

Script :

```
from googletrans import Translator
import argparse
import os
import re
# init the translator
translator = Translator()

def translate(text, src="en", dest="fr"):
    """Translate `text` from `src` language to `dest`"""
    return translator.translate(text, src=src, dest=dest).text
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple Python script to translate text using Google Translate API (googletrans wrapper)")
    parser.add_argument("target", help="Text/Document to translate")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--source", help="Source language, default is Google Translate's auto detection", default="en")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--destination", help="Destination language, default is English", default="fr")
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    target = args.target
    src = args.source
    dest = args.destination
    
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        # translate a document instead
        # get basename of file
        basename = os.path.basename(target)
        # get the path dir
        dirname = os.path.dirname(target)
        try:
            filename, ext = basename.split(".")
        except:
            # no extension
            filename = basename
            ext = ""
            
        #Reading file
        with open(target,mode='r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file_contents = file.read()
            
            text_to_translate = re.findall("'(.+?)'", file_contents)
            text_to_translate = list(set(text_to_translate))
            print(text_to_translate)

            i = 0
            y = 0
            translated_text = text_to_translate.copy()
            fout = open("out.txt", "wt")
            #Translating
            while i < len(translated_text):
                text = translated_text[i]
                translated = translate(text,src=src, dest=dest)
                print(translated)
                translated_text[i] = translated
                i+=1
                
            #Writting to file
            for line in file_contents:
                while y < len(text_to_translate):
                    print("Translation number "+str(y))
                    file.write(line.replace(text_to_translate[y], translated_text[y]))
                    y+=1
            fout.close()

            
    else:
        # not a file, do nothing
        print("wrong file input")
```

Comment: looks like you've opened your file for read only mode. When I normally have to do read write operations, I open one file for read and another file for write; any lines which are not changed are written to the write file, as well as the lines that are changed.

Comment: I managed to correct it by extracting all the values that I need to edit then opening as you said the file in 'w'. Thanks